# Random numbers in Python that are between 2 and 64, but only 2 ** 2

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to write some code to generate random numbers, but the only numbers I want it to generate are 2, 4, 8, 16, 32 and 64 (like a double dice). I have written it out like the below but cant seem to get only the numbers to show up, I keep getting any numbers between 2 and 64. help please.

```
rolling_result = random.randrange(2, 65)

print("You have rolled a ", rolling_result, sep = "")
```

Answer (score 3):

Generate a random number between 1 and 6. Then return 2 to that power.

```
def roll_double_die():
    return 2 ** random.randint(1, 6)
```

Answer (score 2):

Get random between 1-6 and use shift (`<<`) or `2 ** n` to get the final number:

```
n = 1 << random.randrange(1, 7)
# or
n = 2 ** random.randrange(1, 7)
```

Shift should be significantly faster with integers.

Answer (score 0):

and another way, without multiplying:

```
rolling_result = 1
while not rolling_result%2==0:
    rolling_result = random.randrange(2, 65)
print("You have rolled a ", rolling_result, sep = "")
```

HTH, Edwin

[edit] I just found out that random.randrange takes a "step" value, so now your code can become a simple as this:

```
rolling_result = random.randrange(2, 65, 2)
print("You have rolled a ", rolling_result, sep = "")
```

.

Comment: Thanks. I was doing it this way but it was giving me any number between 2 and 64 in multiples of 2. I needed it to just be 2 4 8 16 32 and 64 or 2 to the power of 2. Thank you for your help though

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do it many times it can be effective to pre-generate valid values and use [random.choice()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice).

```
import random

valid = tuple(2 ** x for x in range(1, 7))

def my_random():
  return random.choice(valid)
```

P.S. Depend on size of valid valuesit can be more effective to use list instead of tuple.